# p5.js shader Metaballs issue

Tags: javascript, shader, p5.js

I've attempted to port [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wd3SzS) Shadertoy code into p5.js WebGL, everything works nicely. However instead of passing `xs`, `ys`, `colorRs`, etc, I'd like to pass vec2's and vec3s directly into the uniforms somehow, e.g. `uniform vec2 positions[]`, and `uniform vec3 colors[]`. I've attempted mapping positions and colors just like done with radii, but nothing has worked so far, just a black screen.

Here's what I've tried in `sketch.js`: `metaballShader.setUniform('positions', balls.map(b => [b.pos.x, b.pos.y]));`, and etc for colors.

sketch.js:

```
let metaballShader;
let balls = [];

function preload() {
  metaballShader = loadShader("metaball.vert", "metaball.frag");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(680, 530, WEBGL);
  
  shader(metaballShader);
  
  balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height), [1, 0, 0]));
  balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height), [0, 1, 0]));
  balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height), [0, 0, 1]));
  
  metaballShader.setUniform('width', width);
  metaballShader.setUniform('height', height);
  metaballShader.setUniform('rs', balls.map(b => b.r));
  metaballShader.setUniform('colorRs', balls.map(b => b.color[0]));
  metaballShader.setUniform('colorGs', balls.map(b => b.color[1]));
  metaballShader.setUniform('colorBs', balls.map(b => b.color[2]));
}

function draw() {
  metaballShader.setUniform('xs', balls.map(b => b.pos.x));
  metaballShader.setUniform('ys', balls.map(b => b.pos.y));
  quad(-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
  for (const ball of balls) {
    ball.update(balls);
  }
}
```

ball.js:

```
const BASE_SPEED = 2.5;

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.pos = {
      x: x,
      y: y
    }
    
    this.angle = random(0, 2 * Math.PI);
    
    this.vel = {
      x: BASE_SPEED * cos(this.angle),
      y: BASE_SPEED * sin(this.angle)
    }
    
    this.r = random(0.4, 0.9);
    
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  update() {
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;
    
    if (this.pos.x < 0 || this.pos.x > width) this.vel.x *= -1;
    if (this.pos.y < 0 || this.pos.y > height) this.vel.y *= -1;
  }
}
```

metaball.vert:

```
attribute vec3 aPosition;

uniform float width;
uniform float height;

varying highp vec2 vPos;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);

  vPos = vec2(
    (gl_Position.x + 1.) / 2. * width,
    (gl_Position.y + 1.) / 2. * height
  );
}
```

metaball.frag:

```
precision highp float;

#define BALLS 3

uniform float xs[BALLS];
uniform float ys[BALLS];

uniform float rs[BALLS];

uniform float colorRs[BALLS];
uniform float colorGs[BALLS];
uniform float colorBs[BALLS];

varying highp vec2 vPos;

struct Metaball {
  float r;
  vec2 pos;
  vec3 col;
};

vec4 getDist(Metaball ball) {
  float dist = float(ball.r) / length(vPos - ball.pos);

  return vec4(ball.col * dist, dist);
}

Metaball balls[BALLS];

void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < BALLS; i++) {
    Metaball ball;

    ball.pos = vec2(xs[i], ys[i]);
    ball.r = rs[i];
    ball.col = vec3(colorRs[i], colorGs[i], colorBs[i]);

    balls[i] = ball;
  }

  float total;
  vec3 color;

  for (int i = 0; i < BALLS; i++) {
    vec4 colorValue = getDist(balls[i]);

    total += colorValue.a;
    color += colorValue.rgb;
  }

  float threshold = total > 0.016 ? 1. : 0.;
  color /= total;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(color * threshold, 1.);
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap` or something equivalent to flatten your arrays. For example if you were specifying the value for a `uniform vec2 example[3]` you would want to use something like `setUniform('example', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` as opposed to `setUniform('example', [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])`. Below is a working example.

```js
let metaballShader;
let balls = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(680, 530, WEBGL);
  
  metaballShader = createShader(
    `
attribute vec3 aPosition;

uniform float width;
uniform float height;

varying highp vec2 vPos;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);

  vPos = vec2(
    (gl_Position.x + 1.) / 2. * width,
    (gl_Position.y + 1.) / 2. * height
  );
}`,
    `
precision highp float;

#define BALLS 3

uniform highp vec2 positions[BALLS];

uniform float rs[BALLS];

uniform vec3 colors[BALLS];

varying highp vec2 vPos;

struct Metaball {
  float r;
  highp vec2 pos;
  vec3 col;
};

vec4 getDist(Metaball ball) {
  float dist = float(ball.r) / length(vPos - ball.pos);

  return vec4(ball.col * dist, dist);
}

Metaball balls[BALLS];

void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < BALLS; i++) {
    Metaball ball;

    ball.pos = positions[i];
    ball.r = rs[i];
    ball.col = colors[i];

    balls[i] = ball;
  }

  float total;
  vec3 color;

  for (int i = 0; i < BALLS; i++) {
    vec4 colorValue = getDist(balls[i]);

    total += colorValue.a;
    color += colorValue.rgb;
  }

  float threshold = total > 0.016 ? 1. : 0.;
  color /= total;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(color * threshold, 1.);
}`
  );
  
  shader(metaballShader);
  
  balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height), [1, 0, 0]));
  balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height), [0, 1, 0]));
  balls.push(new Ball(random(width), random(height), [0, 0, 1]));
  
  metaballShader.setUniform('width', width);
  metaballShader.setUniform('height', height);
  metaballShader.setUniform('rs', balls.map(b => b.r));
  metaballShader.setUniform('colors', balls.flatMap(b => b.color));
}

function draw() {
  metaballShader.setUniform('positions', balls.flatMap(b => [b.pos.x, b.pos.y]));
  quad(-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
  for (const ball of balls) {
    ball.update(balls);
  }
}

const BASE_SPEED = 2.5;

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, color) {
    this.pos = {
      x: x,
      y: y
    }
    
    this.angle = random(0, 2 * Math.PI);
    
    this.vel = {
      x: BASE_SPEED * cos(this.angle),
      y: BASE_SPEED * sin(this.angle)
    }
    
    this.r = random(0.4, 0.9);
    
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  update() {
    this.pos.x += this.vel.x;
    this.pos.y += this.vel.y;
    
    if (this.pos.x < 0 || this.pos.x > width) this.vel.x *= -1;
    if (this.pos.y < 0 || this.pos.y > height) this.vel.y *= -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```